# Invoking an initial request before starting to observe changes with observables

Tags: c#, signalr, observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a (classic) SignalR hub which returns the state of some value, with an additional client callback contract that sends updates to the clients. What I'm basically trying to create on the client side (C#) is an observable stream which invokes a task when the first observer connects, and then starts further listening to the changes on the callback contract.

Server contracts (pseudo):

```
interface IMyHub
  Task<int> GetInitialInt();

interface IMyHubClient
  void SendFurtherInts(int value);
```

Client proxy:

```
 var client = hubConnection.CreateObservableHubProxy<IMyHub, IMyHubClient>();
```

I now had imagined something like this:

```
  public IObservable<int> Value { get; }

  var initialData = Observable.FromAsync(async () => 
    await _client.CallAsync(client => client.GetInitialInt));

  var stream = _client.Observe(client => client.SendFurtherInts)
    .StartWith(initialData)
    .Publish()
    .RefCount(1);

  stream.Connect();
  Value = stream.AsObservable();
```

`StartWith()` however expects an enumeration of existing values, not a single value or a stream. `.Prepend()` also doesn't seem to work with streams. I could technically invoke the task first, and then create the stream, but that's neither really functional nor does it fit my needs (invoke when the first observer connects).

What would be the proper way to solve this?

Comment: What about Concat?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?